# Generate a POJO dynamically according to a JSON?

Tags: java, drools

Is it possible to generate a POJO dynamically according to a JSON ,which coming from request body ?
I guess maybe there is a way to convert this JSON to Object, so I can call getters and setters method in my code.
I need this POJO in Drools.

Comment: use `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` classes.. or `JsonNode` if using jackson

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson for the above scenario. Suppose `PojoClass` is the class 
containing the getters and setters of the JSON fields. Then you can use the 
following lines of code:-

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Reader reader = new FileReader("C:\\example.json")
PojoClass pclass = gson.fromJson(reader, PojoClass.class);
```